# Solving integral equation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, integral-equations

How can I solve the following integral equation for $f(x)$ on $x \in [0,1]$?

$$ (f(x) -x) \int_0^1 \left( \frac{\mathrm e^{2-2f(x)}}{\left(\mathrm e^{1-f(x)}+\mathrm e^{1-f(y)}\right)^2}- \frac{\mathrm e^{1-f(x)}}{\mathrm e^{1-f(x)}+\mathrm e^{1-f(y)}} \right) \mathrm dy + \int_0^1 \frac{\mathrm e^{1-f(x)}}{\mathrm e^{1-f(x)}+\mathrm e^{1-f(y)}} \mathrm dy= 0  $$

```
(f[x] - x)*Integrate[Exp[2 - 2 f[x]]/(Exp[1 - f[x]] + Exp[1 - f[y]])^2 - 
Exp[1 - f[x]]/(Exp[1 - f[x]] + Exp[1 - f[y]]), {y, 0, 1}] + 
Integrate[Exp[1 - f[x]]/(Exp[1 - f[x]] + Exp[1 - f[y]]), {y, 0, 1}] == 0
```

Because of the exponential function inside the integral, I don't see how I could transform this into a differential equation to solve with NDSolve.

Comment: Can you provide copy-paste friendly code?

Comment: this cannot be transformed into differential equation.

Comment: @anderstood, I don't yet have any code, because I don't even know where to start.

Comment: @VsevolodA., so how else can I solve this?

Comment: Any additional condition on `f[x]` and `f[y]`?, continuity?, are they monotone?, singularities?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With some effort you can find numerical solution. Let us discretize function `f` at `num` points, e.g. `num=3`. Then, select some integration rule, e.g. Lobatto one:

```
{ab, w, err} = NIntegrate`LobattoRuleData[num, 4]

(* {{0, 0.5000, 1.000}, {0.1667, 0.667, 0.1667}, {}} *)
```

Next, replace `Integrate` with `Sum` at points `ab` with weights `w` and create `Table` of `num` equations evaluating at `x` given by `ab`:

```
sys = Table[
   (f[x] - x)*
     Sum[(Exp[2 - 2 f[x]]/(Exp[1 - f[x]] + Exp[1 - f[y]])^2 - 
         Exp[1 - f[x]]/(Exp[1 - f[x]] + Exp[1 - f[y]]))*
       w[[Position[ab, y][[1, 1]]]], {y, ab}]
    +
    Sum[Exp[1 - f[x]]/(Exp[1 - f[x]] + Exp[1 - f[y]])*
      w[[Position[ab, y][[1, 1]]]], {y, ab}], {x, ab}];
```

Now, create list of unknowns with some starting values:

```
vars = Table[{f[x], 2 + 1/2 x}, {x, ab}]

(* {{f[0], 2}, {f[0.5000], 2.2500}, {f[1.000], 2.5000}} *)
```

and use `FindRoot` to solve system `sys`:

```
FindRoot[sys, vars]

(* {f[0] -> 2.28088, f[0.5000] -> 2.51548, f[1.000] -> 2.78091} *)
```

To get more acurate solution you have to increase `num` and precision of Lobatto rule abscissas and weights. Using `num=64` and 32-digit precision I was able to solve original equation down to `$MachineEpsilon`. Result appear to be roughly linear with rapidly converging polynomial series, starting with:

```
f[x] = 2.28093 + 0.440941 x + 0.0538753 x^2 + 0.00521441 x^3 + 
 0.000168599 x^4
```

Comment: How you compute approximate series `f[x]` ?.Can explain it and add to code?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk `InterpolatingPolynomial` at the points `{ab, f[ab]}`, I think, although I get slightly different coefficients for `x^2` and higher.

Comment: I tried `NonlinearModelFit` and `NMinimize`/`FindRoot` with polynomial (or `LegendreP` expansion) inserted directly into integral equation (solving for coefficients).  Coefficients vary slightly up to `x^3`, but `x^4` term behaves randomly. I'm unable to determine if it is positive  or negative :-(

Answer (score 6):

I liked @Andrzej's approach, so I wrote a complete function to package all the steps.  [Originally, I used barycentric interpolation. Numerically, it's more stable as the number of grid points increases than either Newton interpolation, used by `Interpolation`, or expansion of the polynomial in the power basis.  There's an undocumented built-in function that does this for us, `` Statistics`Library`BarycentricInterpolation ``. With fewer than a 100 or so grid points, it does not matter, except for extrapolation warnings from `InterpolatingFunction` when using a open rule such as Gauss-Legendre quadrature.]

```
ClearAll[findFunc];
SetAttributes[findFunc, HoldFirst];
findFunc[feq_, {f_, f0_}, {x_, a_, b_}, iRule_List] /; Length[iRule] >= 2 :=
  Module[{integrate, sys, vars, ivs, ab, wt, fvals, prec},
   Block[{Integrate = integrate},
    {ab, wt} = iRule[[{1, 2}]];
    prec = Precision[DeleteCases[ab, z_ /; z == 0]] /. 
      Infinity -> MachinePrecision;
    Block[{$MinPrecision = prec, $MaxPrecision = prec},
     ab = Rescale[ab, {0, 1}, {a, b}];
     sys = feq /. Equal -> Subtract /.
          integrate[g_, {y_, a, b}, ___] :> (b - a) wt.(g /. y -> # & /@ ab) /.
         x -> # & /@ ab;
     ];
    vars = f /@ ab;
    ivs = f0 /@ ab;
    fvals = vars /. FindRoot[sys, Transpose@{vars, ivs}, WorkingPrecision -> prec];
    (* {f -> Statistics`Library`BarycentricInterpolation[ab, fvals]} *)
    {f -> Interpolation[Sow@Transpose@{ab, fvals}, InterpolationOrder -> Length@ab - 1]}
    ]];
```

OP's equation:

```
ff = findFunc[
  (f[x] - x)*
    Integrate[Exp[2 - 2 f[x]]/(Exp[1 - f[x]] + Exp[1 - f[y]])^2 - 
      Exp[1 - f[x]]/(Exp[1 - f[x]] + Exp[1 - f[y]]), {y, 0, 1}] + 
   Integrate[Exp[1 - f[x]]/(Exp[1 - f[x]] + Exp[1 - f[y]]), {y, 0, 1}],
  {f, 2 &}, {x, 0, 1},
  NIntegrate`GaussRuleData[16, MachinePrecision]
  ]
```

Check the residual of the solution:

```
check[sol_, x_?NumericQ] :=  (* computes residual of the equation *)
  Block[{f = sol, Integrate = NIntegrate},
   (f[x] - x)*
     Integrate[Exp[2 - 2 f[x]]/(Exp[1 - f[x]] + Exp[1 - f[y]])^2 - 
       Exp[1 - f[x]]/(Exp[1 - f[x]] + Exp[1 - f[y]]), {y, 0, 1}] + 
    Integrate[Exp[1 - f[x]]/(Exp[1 - f[x]] + Exp[1 - f[y]]), {y, 0, 1}]
   ];
Plot[check[f /. ff, x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 500, 
  MaxRecursion -> 0] /. Line -> Point
(* extrapolation warnings *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To get the interpolating polynomial accurately expressed in the power basis, we need to use relatively high arbitrary-precision numbers:

```
idata = Reap[
    findFunc[
     (f[x] - x)*
       Integrate[Exp[2 - 2 f[x]]/(Exp[1 - f[x]] + Exp[1 - f[y]])^2 - 
         Exp[1 - f[x]]/(Exp[1 - f[x]] + Exp[1 - f[y]]), {y, 0, 1}] + 
      Integrate[Exp[1 - f[x]]/(Exp[1 - f[x]] + Exp[1 - f[y]]), {y, 0, 1}],
     {f, 2 &}, {x, 0, 1},
     NIntegrate`GaussRuleData[16, 32]
     ]
    ][[2, 1, 1]];
InterpolatingPolynomial[idata, x] // Expand // N
(*
  2.28093 + 0.440942 x + 0.0538637 x^2 + 0.00526438 x^3 + 
   0.0000719041 x^4 - 0.000111408 x^5 - 0.0000263257 x^6 - 
   2.26604*10^-6 x^7 + 4.33848*10^-7 x^8 + 1.95979*10^-7 x^9 + 
   3.11171*10^-8 x^10 - 1.32086*10^-10 x^11 - 1.72633*10^-9 x^12 - 
   1.62274*10^-10 x^13 - 1.34254*10^-10 x^14 + 4.19153*10^-11 x^15
*)
```

Comment: Er… what's the advantage of `BarycentricInterpolation` compared to `Interpolation`?

Comment: @xzczd Hmm, I hadn't checked. I think barycentric interpolation is numerically more stable than Newton interpolation, which is used by Interpolation. That seems only to matter once you get a 100 or 200 grid nodes.  In this case, the solution is nearly a straight line, so just a few nodes are needed. Thanks