# Integro-differential equation with parameters

Tags: differential-equations, mathematical-optimization, integral-equations

I am trying to solve an optimization problem with constraints that leads to the following integro-differential equation

```
Log[f'[x0]]*Exp[f[x0]] + Integrate[ (f'[x]*Log[f'[x]] - f'[x] + 1)*Exp[f[x]], {x,x0,xmax}] - c == 0
```

The goal is to find `f[x]` such that this equation holds for all `x0` between `0` and `xmax=10`. The parameter `c` comes from a Lagrange multiplier that imposes the constraint `f[xmax] == 10`, and we have the initial condition `f[0] == 0`. In an analytical approach, one would solve the integro-differential equation for `f[x]` in terms of `c`, plug the result in the constraint equation to find the value for `c`, and eventually substitute the resulting value in the expression for `f`.

I am not sure how I can go about solving this numerically (or analytically, but I doubt that'd be possible). I have seen a few posts dealing with integral equations and integro-differential equations (like [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148541/numerically-solve-an-integro-differential-equation) or [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/166830/solving-integral-equation)). However, it appears to me that these approaches do not directly apply to my case, since (a) differentiating the equation doesn't seem to simplify it much and (b) I have an undetermined parameter `c` that needs to be determined through the constraint equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А ларчик просто открывался.
Let us differentiate this equation with respect to `x0`.

```
D[Log[f'[x0]]*Exp[f[x0]], x0] +  
D[Integrate[(f'[x]*Log[f'[x]] - f'[x] + 1)*Exp[f[x]], {x, x0,   xmax}], x0] == 0
```

> `E^f[x0] Log[Derivative[1][f][x0]] Derivative[1][f][x0] -  E^f[x0] (1 - Derivative[1][f][x0] +  Log[Derivative[1][f][x0]] Derivative[1][f][x0]) + ( E^f[x0] (f^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x0])/Derivative[1][f][x0] == 0`

```
DSolve[%, f[x0], x0]
```

> `{{f[x0]->Subscript[\[ConstantC], 2]+Log[E^x0+E^Subscript[\[ConstantC], 1]]}}`